# Scroll the ScrollView when contain the ListView

Tags: android

I have an issue and need your help.
I have and ScrollView and have two ListViews inside. But i can not scroll the ScrollView.
How can i let the ScrollView scroll?

Thanks for any help
Clark

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not do this . Because list view are already scrollable so you should not put it in another scroll view

its worth to watch this link 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70